# Div's with same class, toggle classes

Tags: html, css, toggle

I'm trying to make an itemlist like in a shopping basket.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.itemthumbnail').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("fit");
  });
});
```

```css
#itemlist{
  background-color: #19191d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
.itemthumbnail{
  border: 1px solid #33353e;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #262629;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.itemthumbnail:hover {
  background-color: #3b3b40;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.99); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.99); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(0.99); 
}
.fit{
  background-color: #131315;
  border:2px solid #278c2e;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.95); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(0.95); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemlist">
 <div class="itemthumbnail">
     <div class="itemname">Sweater</div> 
     <div class="itemprice">19.99 $</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For every item in the basket it will load the class itemthumbnail.
I want when someone click on it to look like "selected" and thats what i made the class "fit" for. But i cant get it to work. I searched now for few hours to find a solution but nothing helped me out.

If i put the js click event to `$('Button').click...` it works. Have no idea at this time how to solve this. Would be happy about every hint.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that you wish to toggle all the divs with class="itemthumbnail" when clicking on only one of those?

Comment: i only want to toggle the class to the one which is clicked. Like u select 4 items to delete from basket. I found now a solution with with $(document).on('click', '.itemthumbnail', function() { 
      $(this).toggleClass('fit');
    });  This works well dont know why my original code wont do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this code**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery('.itemthumbnail').click(function(){
      jQuery('.itemthumbnail').removeClass("fit");
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("fit");
  });
});
```

```css
#itemlist{
  background-color: #19191d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
.itemthumbnail{
  border: 1px solid #33353e;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #262629;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.itemthumbnail:hover {
  background-color: #3b3b40;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.99); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.99); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(0.99); 
}
.fit{
  background-color: #131315;
  border:2px solid #278c2e;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.95); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(0.95); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemlist">
 <div class="itemthumbnail">
   <div class="itemname">Sweater</div> 
   <div class="itemprice">19.99 $</div>
 </div>
 <div class="itemthumbnail">
   <div class="itemname">Sweater</div> 
   <div class="itemprice">19.99 $</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daniel: If my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. the thing is the code i posted here works in the "Run code Snippet" box but didnt work on my site. After i changed it to $(document).on('click', '.itemthumbnail', function() { it worked on my site aswell. i have no idea why it work here in the snippet box but not on my site. weird!

Comment: that i solved the problem now i can accept your answer but have no idea how to do ? dont find a button to accept or close the request.

Comment: @Daniel: Please see this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for how to accept answer